# Sql Server copy row and change one column by increment

Tags: sql, copy

I've a db with four fields id, code,country, price. I want to duplicate one product and to increment its price.

Example: for object(1,'Toy','us', 100), I want to get a new object with price +10 (2,'Toy','us',110).

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table
          ( ID
          ...., 
           Price
          )
     (SELECT ID
          ...., 
           Price+10)
```

Is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible if one of the following is true:

- `ID` is an [`IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) column, or
- You can make a formula for producing an `ID` of a column to be inserted, given the `ID` of the original column.

For the `IDENTITY` column solution, omit the ID from your `INSERT` statement, like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
      (  ...,  Price
      )
 (SELECT ..., Price+10)
```

For a formula-based solution, add a formula for the `ID`:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
      (ID, ...,  Price
      ) -- The formula for the new ID below is NewID = 10000+OldID
 (SELECT ID+10000, ..., Price+10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `SELECT` in `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table(ID,..., Price)
SELECT 2, ..., Price+10
WHERE ID = 1
```